# StanfordPOSTagger not working with NLTK

Tags: java, python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm having trouble getting the latest StanfordPOSTagger to work in python 2.7.1 with NLTK 3.2.1 on a mac with Java 8 installed.  I have found several other threads with very similar problems, but none of the solutions there has worked for me..  Below is the output when I try to tag a sentence:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
>>> st = StanfordPOSTagger('wsj-0-18-left3words-distsim.tagger')
>>> st.tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("This is a test"))
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
st.tag(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize("This is a test"))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 71, in tag
return sum(self.tag_sents([tokens]), [])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 94, in tag_sents
stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 134, in java
raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['/Library/Java/Home/bin/java', '-mx1000m', '-cp', '/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger-3.6.0-javadoc.jar:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger-3.6.0-sources.jar:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger-3.6.0.jar:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/lib/slf4j-api.jar:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/lib/slf4j-simple.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger', '-model', '/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/models/wsj-0-18-left3words-distsim.tagger', '-textFile', '/var/folders/gy/bw2lj_wj79x9vl1l3n3ccg980000gn/T/tmp6yV_lP', '-tokenize', 'false', '-outputFormatOptions', 'keepEmptySentences', '-encoding', 'utf8']
```

Inside my .bash_profile file I have added the following two lines:

```
export CLASSPATH={CLASSPATH}:/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar
export STANFORD_MODELS=/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/models
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```

There seem to be several other places with Java home folders and java executables, but I've tried using them all and nothing works.  I have also tried the solution here:https://gist.github.com/alvations/e1df0ba227e542955a8a which was posted by a few people in different threads, but that hasn't worked either.. I'll be extremely grateful if anyone can help me to solve this!

Comment: Does the command work outside of linux?

Comment: I think it's a permission issue. Do you have access to `/Library/Java/Home/bin/`, `/Users/johntorr/VirtualAssistantProject/stanford-postagger/` and `/var/folders/`?

Comment: Try `sudo chmod u+w -R /Library/Java/Home/bin/*`, `sudo chmod u+w -R /var/folders/` on your terminal.

Comment: Also, update your Java and install Java 8, that should resolve most java-related problems when using Stanford tools.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your advice Alvas.. Actually I managed to solve the problem by installing the following older version of the POS tagger from 2014 that still has all the imperatives: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-postagger-full-2014-01-04.zip
Apparently there is precisely the same problem with the latest Stanford parser and so people have been using a 2014 version of that too..